# The Hausdorff measure of the unit interval

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, hausdorff-measure, dimension-theory-analysis, fractal-analysis

I am trying to calculate the Hausdorff measure of the unit interval. Here's my attempt:

Fix $\epsilon>0$.

consider the open balls $B(x,\epsilon)$ with $x\in[0,1]$. How many can cover the unit interval? at least $\frac{1}{2\epsilon}$. So if we use $\lfloor{}\frac{1}{2\epsilon}\rfloor{}+1$ $\epsilon$-balls we will definitely cover the interval. So we have:

$$H^\delta([0,1])\le{}H^\delta_\epsilon([0,1])\le{}\sum_{i=1}^{\lfloor{}\frac{1}{2\epsilon}\rfloor{}+1}{(2\times\epsilon)^\delta}=(\lfloor{}\frac{1}{2\epsilon}\rfloor{}+1)(2\epsilon)^\delta\le{}(\frac{1}{2\epsilon}+1)(2\epsilon)^\delta$$

But here, I don't think this works as taking the limit $\epsilon\to0$ blows up the upper bound
Is there any way to lower bound this to show that it is 1?

Comment: Your are calculating its Hausdorff $\delta$-dimensional measure! So for $\delta >1$, it will be $0$, and for $\delta <1$, it will be $+\infty$!

Comment: Sorry, I'm abit confused then on how one would show this.

Comment: Oh I see, how silly of me, ive edited now. See, I am trying to show that  the Hausdorff measure of a set need not be the same as the Hausdorff measure of a sets closure. So I'm trying to calculate the Hausdorff measure (with $\delta=1/2$) of $[0,1]$ and $\mathbb{Q}\cap{}[0,1]$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(answer for the original question.)

Take $\delta=1$, then the limit $\epsilon \to 0$.  Your calculation shows
$$
H^1([0,1]) \le 1
$$
Proof of the lower bound will also be needed:
$$
H^1([0,1]) \ge 1
$$
But this is much harder.  It can be done using properties of the Lebesgue measure.
It is often true in estimation of Hausdorff measure.  The upper bound it easy, the lower bound is hard.

---

Now a comment for the edited question.  With $\delta < 1$ you should get $H^\delta([0,1]) = \infty$.  Your calculation shows
$$
H^{\delta}([0,1]) \le +\infty
$$
which is not very useful.  You will need to prove a lower bound,
$$
H^{\delta}([0,1]) > 0
$$
As I remarked before, the lower bound is the harder one to prove.

It is easy to show $H^\delta(\mathbb Q \cap [0,1]) = 0$, so then you will know that the measures of the set and its closure are different.

Comment: Ok thanks. Im reading through some notes at the moment and around this area specifically there is mention of a mass distribution theorem which provides a lower bound to the Hausdorff dimension. Would this be a good place to start with the lower bound?

Comment: Yes, providing a measure, and using that, is often a good way to prove a lower bound.

Comment: (+1) for the line "The upper bound it easy, the lower bound is hard" alone.  This a fact which is so often true:  for Hausdorff measure, Minkowski content, Assouad dimension, and so on.

Comment: @XanderHenderson  On the other hand, for packing measure we often have  the lower bound easy, the upper bound hard.

Comment: @GEdgar Perhaps it would be better to say that there is always a hard bound.  Obtaining upper bounds for the lower dimension (a dual to the Assouad dimension) is also the hard part.